# Custom UIViewController's view is not being shown

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, xib

So i have this view controller and it has a xib file, i checked for File's Owner and also the view outlet, both class and xib files are connected. But if i want to push this view controller it will show an empty one even if all its methods are being called: `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`

```
self.navigationController?.presentViewController(
  TourViewController(nibName: "TourViewController", bundle: nil), animated: false, completion: nil
)
```

This is the view controller:

```
class TourViewController: TLViewController {

  override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    println("nib init")
  }

  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    println("didLoad")

  }

  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    println("appear")
  }

}
```

I changed the color background and also i added a label to XIB

Comment: I never used XIB files with Swift

Comment: Use live view debugging and see if something is covering it

Comment: @DreamingInBinary, live view debugging is an amazing tool, thanks, i need to look at the WWDC videos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem was in my CUSTOM `TLViewController`

```
override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    screen = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    visibleFrame = CGRectMake(
      0.0,
      20.0 + 44.0,
      screen.size.width,
      screen.size.height - (20.0 + 44.0)
    )

    view = UIView(frame: screen)
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.backgroundMenu()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes =
      [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.backgroundMenu()]
    // Back Button
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "",
      style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)

    var menuBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
    menuBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "menu-ico"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    menuBtn.addTarget(self, action: Selector("menu"), forControlEvents:  UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    leftMenuButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: menuBtn)
  }
```

So i changed

```
class TourViewController: TLViewController
```

to

```
class TourViewController: UIViewController
```

Comment: You shouldn't be calling super.loadView().